# CLViewController, display detail view in fullscreen, iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, cascade

I am working on iOS application and i have used the split view like structure which Facebook application has.

I have used the code which has the **CLViewController**, This code i have found from google.

All working fine but in my current application when the app loads the first screen itself shows the **split view** in which 80% screen shows the menu and 20% shows the detail page. I want to change it in a way the Facebook app works. In **Facebook on loading app directly shows the news feed**. so same way i want to load detail page first.

If anyone have any idea how can i achieve it please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code : How to use SWRevealViewController

Here first initialize your View controllers

```
FirstViewController * first = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
SecondViewController * second = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
```

Create BarButton....

```
UIBarButtonItem *revealButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:_revealVC action:@selector(revealToggleAnimated:)];
```

Put firstViewController and secondViewController into Navigation
First hide self.navigationbar
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

```
UINavigationController * navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];
navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButton


UINavigationController * navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButton
```

Initialize SWRevealViewController

```
_revealVC= [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:navigationController1 frontViewController:navigationController2];

_revealVC.rightViewController =nil;

_revealVC.rearViewRevealWidth = 60;
_revealVC.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0;

_revealVC.bounceBackOnOverdraw = YES;
_revealVC.stableDragOnOverdraw = YES;

_revealVC.rightViewRevealWidth = 350;
_revealVC.rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0;

[_revealVC setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionRight];

[_revealVC revealToggleAnimated:YES];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_revealVC] animated:true];
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get `Split View` you are looking for [Click Here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

Comment: Thank for your comment, I have already used this CLViewController and doesn't want to change the whole application for it. so if you have any idea of how to do it in current structure would be great.

Comment: You can use only  SWRevealViewController.h/m files, no need to create new project, thanx

Comment: Thanks for comment... Can you please explain with some example so can understand it. I tried but I am unable to do it. if you can please add some code would be great help.